# fill multi columns from one dataframe to another with matching field

Tags: python

I have one dataframe as main data, and would like to take information from another dataframe based on matching field.

df1

| Id | ColA | 401Col1 | 401Col2 | 401Color | 402Col1 | 402Col2 | 402Col3 | 402Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00102J | 123 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00206B | 345 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

df2

| Id | Table | Color | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00102J | 401 | red | hhy2023876 |
| 00102J | 402 | yellow | 01/09/82 |
| 00102J | 403 | red | location/new/yes |
| 00206B | 402 | white | 02/45/23 |
| 00206B | 405 | black | 0 3 5 2 6 1 |

for each Table (401, 402, 403, 405), I would like to extract information with fixed width from Data column

for Table 401,  turn hhy2023876 -> hhy and 2023 and fill them into 401Col1 and 401Col2

for Table 402,  turn 01/09/82 -> 01 09 82 and fill them into 402Col1, 402Col2, 402Col3

and fill 401/402 Color column with Color field from df2

I've so far created definition of width for 401, 402, 403, 405

401 = [(0,3), (3,7)]

402 = [(0,2), (3,5), (6,8)]

403 = [(10,14)]

405 = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)]

would like to have an output like this, thank you!

df1

| Id | ColA | 401Col1 | 401Col2 | 401Color | 402Col1 | 402Col2 | 402Col3 | 402Color | 403Col1 | 403Color | 405Col1 | 405Col2 | 405Col3 | 405Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00102J | 123 | hhy | 2023 | red | 01 | 09 | 82 | yellow | new | red |  |  |  |  |
| 00206B | 345 |  |  |  | 02 | 45 | 23 | white |  |  | 0 | 3 | 5 | black |